# PDF Unicode Text Not Encoding Properly

Tags: pdf, unicode, character-encoding, adobe, acrobat

I have asked this question on Upwork.com and Adobe Support forums but no one has been able to provide an answer.

When I convert a Microsoft Word document to PDF (using either the Adobe Printer or Save As > PDF), the Unicode text in the document does not encode properly. The text *appears* correct, but when I copy and paste it to another program, such as Notepad, there are errors:

For example, the text in Microsoft Word is

`बूढ़े पिता ने ऐसी भूमिका ...`

The text *appears* correct in the PDF file, but when I copy and paste it Notepad, it is:

`बूढ़े पता ने ऐसी भूमका ...`

Note the boxes.

This erroneous encoding means it is not possible to search the PDF document properly. For example, if I search for `पिता` (the second word), I will not get a match. I would have to search `पता`.

Embedding the fonts makes no difference.

Please advise how I can create a PDF properly, so that the encoding is exactly like it is in any other program, i.e. without any of these boxes or other issues.

Thank you

Comment: Apparently the programs you use to create those pdfs have bugs (or miss features) relevant to your use case. Thus, issue bug reports. Probably first at Microsoft as you can reproduce the issue with word alone.

Comment: Every program results in a similar issue. If I right click on the file and convert to PDF using the Adobe converter. there is the same issue.

Comment: No problem with the PDF exporter in Libreoffice 6.3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmYGz.png